# Chaos Emperor Dragon vs materials

Tags: yu-gi-oh

[Chaos Emperor Dragon - Envoy of the End](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Chaos_Emperor_Dragon_-_Envoy_of_the_End):

> Cannot be Normal Summoned/Set. Must be Special Summoned (from your
>   hand) by banishing 1 LIGHT and 1 DARK monster from your GY. You can
>   pay 1000 Life Points; send as many cards in both players' hands and on
>   the field as possible to the GY, then inflict 300 damage to your
>   opponent for each card sent to the opponent's GY by this effect. You
>   cannot activate other cards or effects during the turn you activate
>   this card's effect.

Does material cards attached to monster are counted to inflict 300 each?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## No, the Materials Will Not Count Toward the Damage Inflicted

Let us examine the effect of Chaos Emperor Dragon again, this time with a bit more scrutiny (emphasis mine):

> You can pay 1000 Life Points; send as many cards **in both players' hands and on the field** as possible to the GY, then inflict 300 damage to your opponent for each card **sent to the opponent's GY by this effect**.

The specific wording of the highlighted text is crucial to understanding why the materials are not included. Importantly, no matter the chain of strategic causality (i.e., "Without activating that effect, those materials would never have been sent to the GY"), it is *not* the effect of Chaos Emperor Dragon that is sending the materials to the GY.

**Any materials attached to the XYZ monster are sent to the GY due to the XYZ monster leaving the field - NOT due to Chaos Emperor Dragon's effect.**

Think of it this way: at the moment prior to the effect's resolution, there is an exact set of cards existing on the field and in the hand(s) - this is the set of cards which will be considered sent to the GY by Chaos Emperor Dragon, per the wording in its own effect. Note that any materials on any XYZ monsters on the field are *not* a part of this set. This is due to [the way Yu-Gi-Oh treats XYZ materials](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Xyz_Material) with respect to Zone habitance:

> Xyz Materials are not treated as being on the field

Again, I cannot emphasize this enough, it *does not matter* that the XYZ materials were sent to the grave during the resolution of the effect - they were not sent *by* the effect of Chaos Emperor Dragon. They will not be counted toward the damage inflicted.

Comment: I guess you're right, since Xyz materials not treated on the field, then they are not counted

Comment: Your arguments and quotes have convinced me that you are right :) as the materials are not on the field nor hand it does not count to the damage.

Answer (score 0):

During the Xyz era it was ruled that Xyz materials are no longer considered on the field. (This would be too strong with cards like Sangan, Burning Abyss...)
So since they are not sent from the field to the grave, no damage will be inflicted for them by Chaos Emperor Dragon.

Comment: Although you are correct that they are not in the field, Chaos emperor Dragon does not specify that they have to be on the field. It just says "For each card sent to the Opponents GY", so those cards do count for damage.

Comment: @DarkCygnus it also says "send as many cards in both players' hands and on the field as possible to the GY". The effect to do damage, only counts the cards sent to the graceyard by the effect (for each card sent to the opponent's GY by this effect). The Xyz materials are sent to the grave by game mechangics, And so do not count.

Comment: I don't agree on that. Without activating the effect those materials wouldn't have been sent to the gy

Comment: Let me put it like this. If you had a monster, equiped with an equip spell card. And your opponent activates dark hole. The monster is destroyed and the spell card goes to the graveyard. Would you consider the spell card destroyed by dark hole? No, offcourse not, it was sent to the graveyard by game mechanics. Something similar happens here.